# What do the parameters used in crop mean?

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to crop an image properly. Lets say my image is called `frame` and `x`, `y`, `w` and `h` are `xmin`, `ymin`, `xmax` and `ymax`, respectively:

```
frame = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w] #Crop a part of the image
```

What does `y:y` or `x:x` mean and why do we sum them to `h` and `w`, respectively?

I've been seeing some people performing the crop in the following way:

```
frame = frame[y:h, x:w] #Crop a part of the image without adding to `w` and `h`
```

I saw the second approach being used in some places like in the following line: https://github.com/balajisrinivas/Face-Mask-Detection/blob/master/detect_mask_video.py#L51

What's the difference?

Comment: `w` and `h` are not `xmax` and `ymax`, they are width and height. The first line only works if you're using Python, otherwise it will be off by one. I've never seen the second one, you would have to provide a citation.

Comment: So how do you consider the  `xmax` and `ymax` in the annotations files?

About the citation of someone using the second approach, take a look here: https://github.com/balajisrinivas/Face-Mask-Detection/blob/master/detect_mask_video.py#L51

Comment: I mean, waht's the difference between (`xmin`, `ymin`, `xmax` `ymax`) and (`x`, `y`, `width`, `height`)? I've been thinking that's the same. If I'm mistaken at that point, please help me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got some misunderstanding about how indexing and slicing in numpy works:

For your first line `y:y + h` basically means `slice from index y to index y + h`. Same goes for the second dimension, there you take the array `slice from x to x + w`.

So basically `x` and `y` correspond to your `xmin` and `ymin` and you slice to `xmax` and `ymax` which is the window minimums plus the corresponding height and width; that's why you have `y + h` and `x + w` in the second part of both dimensions.

As for `frame[y:y, x:x]` - this makes no sense at least in python, so you might have mixed up something there. If you slice from the index to the same index, your resulting array will always be empty:

```
frame = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
slice = frame[2:2, 2:2]
print(slice)
# []
```

You might want to review the basic idea behind indexing and slicing in numpy here:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: You're very right about my missunderstanding related to how slicing in numpy works. That's for your response. Just reading so I can accept the answer.

Comment: Let me edit a bit. What about `frame = frame[y:h, x:w]`

Comment: I guess this can work, but only if the window is in the upper left corner, therefore y=x=0

Comment: Can we see the image when `x` = `y`?

Comment: What do you mean by see the image? x and y are just the coordinates of the upper left corner. The resulting sub image depends on the slice you choose.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. By see the image I mean why you referred when you talked about sllices. On my understanding now, the values of `width` and `height` will define the box size.

Comment: I appreciate a lot. Everything undestood now.